# How can I check if a gulp task is running?

Tags: node.js, gulp, development-environment, livereload

I'm running a development livereload server with [gulp-server-livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-server-livereload). This is the `default` task in gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var server = require('gulp-server-livereload');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  gulp.src(basePath)
    .pipe(server({
      livereload: true,
      host: domain,
      port: 80,
    }));
});
```

Then there's another task, `gulp export`, which requires this running web server. If I start another one it gives an error (because the ports 80 and 35729 are busy). So the logic I'm going for is this:

if `gulp default` is already running, dive right into nightmare.js tasks
else start a server and proceed to nightmare.js tasks

So my problem is I don't know **a robust way to check if a gulp task is running**.

Can I do that with some Gulp method? Or from the level of Node?
I wouldn't like to check open ports or webserver address as a proxy for "yes default task is running" if at all possible.

Comment: In development environment you can display a information on console or using a log.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do that with some Gulp method? Or from the level of Node? I wouldn't like to check open ports or webserver address as a proxy for "yes default task is running" if at all possible.

I have found no `gulp` way so far, so here is checking for ports busy. If they are it infers the server is running and proceeds with the `export` tasks, if not it starts a server.

```
var server = require('gulp-server-livereload');

gulp.task('export', function () {

  var net = require('net');

  var portFree = function(port, callback) {
    var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
      socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
      socket.pipe(socket);
    });

    server.listen(port, '127.0.0.1');
    server.on('error', function (e) {
      callback(false);
    });
    server.on('listening', function (e) {
      server.close();
      callback(true);
    });
  };

  portFree(35729, function(returnValue) {
    // If server isn't already running, start it.
    if(returnValue) {
      gulp.src(basePath)
      .pipe(server({
        livereload: true,
        host: 'http://localhost'
      }));
    }
  });

  // Do the actual export tasks...
});
```